# SSIS Transfer Login Task Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, logins, sql-server-2017

I have created an SSIS Transfer Logins Task. I have selected the `SourceConnection` and `DestinationConnection` and both valid and active.

I have selected certain Windows group accounts to transfer from source to destination databases. `IfObjectExists` is set to `'Overwrite'` and `CopySids` is `'True'`.

When I run the task I get the following error:

> *SSIS package "F:\SQL Server\SSDT\acQuire Migration\acQuire Migration SSIS\acQuire Migration SSIS\Package.dtsx" starting.
>   
>  Error: 0xC002F325 at Transfer Logins Task, Transfer Logins Task: Execution failed with the following error: "An exception occurred in SMO.".
>   
>  Error: 0xC002F325 at Transfer Logins Task, Transfer Logins Task: Execution failed with the following error: "Value cannot be null.
>   
>  Parameter name: server".
>   
>  Task failed: Transfer Logins Task
>   
>  Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
>   
> SSIS package "F:\SQL Server\SSDT\acQuire Migration\acQuire Migration SSIS\acQuire Migration SSIS\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
>   
> The program '[1868] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of going through the rabbit hole of finding a fix for the error, I would highly suggest you use [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/)

[Copy-DbaLogin](https://dbatools.io/functions/copy-dbalogin/)

> This command migrates logins from source to destination SQL Servers. Supports SQL Server versions 2000 and above. Migrates logins with
>
> SIDs
>
> passwords
>
> defaultdb
>
> server roles & securables
>
> database permissions & securables
>
> login attributes (enforce password policy, expiration, language, etc).

e.g.

```
Copy-DbaLogin -Source sqlserver -Destination sqlcluster
```

and there are [many more commands](https://dbatools.io/functions/) that will make your life easier

Comment: Thank @Kin.  I had read about that on some sites but had not jumped into it yet.